# Как создать загрузочную запись при установке ArchLinux на внешний SSD?

Tags: linux, grub, archlinux, ssd, uefi

При установке ArchLinux на внешний SSD все идет хорошо ровно до установки grub и создания загрузочной записи. Пробовал разные места установки и флаги, UEFI его не видит. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: «разные места установки» — какие? «и флаги» — какие?

Comment: Ну и очевидное — документацию-то читали? https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GRUB

Comment: специально для такого случая есть статья на арчвики - [Install Arch Linux on a removable medium](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Install_Arch_Linux_on_a_removable_medium)